# How to clean/flush stored ip info for websites?

Tags: ping

I am trying to check whether I am connected to internet or not by using shell script.
I think that I can do it by using **ping** command, since if ping succeed there is an IP info inside parenthesis. If there is no parenthesis, then I use **cut** command to assign a specific variable which becomes null if that is the case.

So I wrote below code :

```bsh
echo " First check whether internet is working or not  : "
internetCheck=$(ping -c 1 google.com | cut -s -d "(" -f1)
if [ -z "$internetCheck" ]; then 
  echo "NO INTERNET CONNECTION FOUND !"
else 
  echo "[ OK ] Internet is connected.\n"
fi
```

And it worked. However, when I close the connection,and when I repeat the script for the same website(google.com), system(?) remembers the last ping command's result so it fails. How can I clean/flush previous pings' results?

Comment: ping google DNS, 8.8.8.8 instead of google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better test, no need for grep...

```
echo " First check whether internet is working or not  : "
if ping -q -c 1 <host> > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
  echo "[ OK ] Internet is connected.\n"
else 
  echo "NO INTERNET CONNECTION FOUND !"
fi
```

Comment: The manual page I have for `ping` doesn't document the return code. If your `ping` does say it return true if any packets get returned then yes, avoiding the grep is great.

Comment: @icarus `If  ping  does  not  receive any reply packets at all it will exit with code 1. If a packet count and deadline are both specified, and fewer than count packets are received by the time the deadline has arrived, it will also exit with code 1.  On other error it exits
       with code 2. Otherwise it exits with code 0. This makes it possible to use the exit code to see if a host is alive or not.`

Comment: @Bib If this is documented then great. It isn't documented on my system, although it looks a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @icarus You could tell us which system you have and whether it works!

Comment: My system doesn't document the return code for ping. This is common, e.g. https://linux.die.net/man/8/ping for the gnu network utilities.

Comment: @icarus, Please read that man page again. The return codes are there. Search for the word `alive` on that page and you will get the exact paragraph I posted. And fwiw, I am running opensuse which has those utilities. I really cannot see how you can miss it since it is the 2nd paragraph after all the options descriptions.

Comment: I missed it as I expect there to be a section with heading return code towards the end, and a search for `return` doesn't find anything. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 1):

Converting the name to the IP address is usually done by your local DNS resolver, and is indeed cached. This is why you can get the address even if you are not connected.

A better thing to look for would be `100% packet loss` so here is a modified version of your script.

```
echo " First check whether internet is working or not  : "
if ping -c 1 google.com | grep -qE '100% packet loss|Temporary failure in name resolution' ; then 
  echo "NO INTERNET CONNECTION FOUND !"
else 
  echo "[ OK ] Internet is connected.\n"
fi
```

Comment: If there's no connection the message is `ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`.

Comment: That is for the case where you haven't already been connected and run the script, or the value has timed out of the cache. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: You'd be better pinging by address than by name. It reduces the problem complexity by removing the dependency on a caching DNS service. Any of 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 9.9.9.9 could be your starting point

Comment: @roaima I agree. I was answering the question as asked  which is essentially "why does ping report the ip address when it is not connected to the internet if I do it a second time?" I was of course thinking of using an IP address when I only checked for 100% packet loss.